# How to represent multiple values for a single node in XML?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <code_details>
        <summer_redeem_code>54</summer_redeem_code>
        <winter_redeem_code>38</winter_redeem_code>
    </code_details>
```

In the above code, think of summer_redeem_code and winter_redeem_code as tags that want to store multiple values. Imagine that summer_redeem_code is passed values such as 54,56,57 but only the first one i.e. 54 can be displayed. Also, winter_redeem_code is passed values such as 38,48,58 but only the first one i.e. 38 can be displayed.

**Question:** I am trying to figure out what is the best way to represent multiple values for a single element/attribute/tag in XML so that I can display more than just the first one that I can do for now?

Currently these tags are 1:1 relationship and I want to make them 1-many (if that makes sense?). Basically, looking for a method(tags) that can accommodate all the values.

**Constraints:**
1) tags summer_redeem_code and winter_redeem_code cannot be deleted as they would break a parser that cannot be modified. 

Possible solution: This would probably require leaving them as is and introducing a new 1-many item with a new tag - maybe "redeem_codes" and putting those under it.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you would like to do...magine that summer_redeem_code is passed values such as 54,56,57 but only the first one i.e. 54 can be displayed. Why is so? Do you have any control of the format? Or you can only control the parsing the code?

Comment: Good question. The data is fetched from another feed (over which I have no control) and stored into those two tags. Currently, the fetch logic is able to fetch only the first value (if they have multiple) for any given node. I am seeking to expand the logic to fetch multiple but before that wanted to know how I could represent them in XML, hence the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common ways of doing this are:

1. Wrapped sequences of elements

   ```
   <codes>
     <winter>
       <winterCode>54</winterCode>
       <winterCode>58</winterCode>
       <winterCode>92</winterCode>
     </winter>
     <summer>
       <summerCode>85</summerCode>
       <summerCode>32</summerCode>
     </summer>
   </codes>
   ```

(2) The same without the wrapper elements

```
<codes>
    <winterCode>54</winterCode>
    <winterCode>58</winterCode>
    <winterCode>92</winterCode>
    <summerCode>85</summerCode>
    <summerCode>32</summerCode>
 </codes>
```

(3) List-valued content

```
 <codes>
    <winterCode>54 58 92</winterCode>
    <summerCode>85 32</summerCode>
</codes>
```

Choosing between these involves trade-offs: ease of creating the content, ease of validating, ease of reading the content, size, compatibility with the past, extensibility into the future. Only you can decide what's right for you.